# Issue with modify keyword in drools

Tags: drools

I have two rules.

Rule-1 : Inside then clause, I have **modify($l) { setInsiderLoanYN("N") };**

Rule-2: Inside when clause, I have **$m : LoanApplication(insiderLoanYN == "N")**

Issue: Rule-1 is executed fine. But, the set value isn't evaluated in then clause of Rule-2. What is the issue here? How can I use modified fact attribute to check it's value in subsequent rules?

Help is greatly appreciated with an example pl.!

Comment: are you sure second rule is executed?

Comment: Providing two snippets out of context isn't going to produce a useful answer. Rules in full and the fact(s) you insert, including their Java class: that's the minimum.

Comment: @piyushj, second rule was not executing earlier. But I identified the problem. There was another Rule-3 which I am setting a field and using it in when clause of Rule-2 posted above besides checking value for insiderLoanYN. So, I didn't use modify in Rule-3. That was the reason why Rule-2 not getting executed.

Comment: @laune apologize for the short description of issue. Figured out the issue. Thanks for the help.