# Drools LHS How to update map

Tags: drools

Sorry for my bad expression. Actually I asked one of my friends who majored in English but knew little about programming to revise my posting. And it turns out that the problem makes less sense, though. I've conducted some research and realized that I should learn more about Drools for my next asking. Thanks for your patience, and the question will be deleted.

Comment: ... Your question makes even less sense now. The original question made it clear that the problem was that you changed a value in the map and called `update` in rule 1, but rule 2 still fired even though its condition was no longer valid. Now it just says "rule-2 LHS is not updated" which doesn't actually _mean_ anything....

Answer (score 1):

I've created a simple reproducer to understand better what's happening. You can find the project that fires both rules [here](https://github.com/lucamolteni/68691187). I [always suggest](https://youtu.be/IdS7dgSj3ds?list=PL2EZpw0rKSMblxCPom7E9Q1O9qVMH2t-x&t=1860) trying to create a simple reproducer with the Drools archetype because it's easier to understand what's happening.

Having said that, your second rule is not firing because the condition `this["ISELSE"] != "TRUE"` is not satisfied. In fact you can see you put the value of the map to true in the first consequence.

```
$map.put("ISELSE", "TRUE");
```

A few other details:

You shouldn't do pattern matching on such a generic type such as `java.util.Map`. Use a specific type that wraps a Map. Be as specific as possible in your pattern matching constraints.

Also why using string booleans instead of java booleans? Drools supports all Java type system, and it's probably better to use better data types.

In the video you'll find some other suggestion such as using `DebugAgendaEventListener` to understand rules evaluation

Comment: It's hard to understand what OP means by "rule-2 LHS is not updated", but I _think_ the problem is that he expects _not_ to fire because he set the value in rule 1's RHS and called update. The original revision actually was a little clearer: "it can't update at rule-2 so that rule-2 will not match".

Comment: I see, in that case I hope he answers otherwise we'll vote to close it - my suggestions still apply though :)

Answer (score 0):

Rules matching is indeterministic process, you can't predict LHS matching order.
Once matching process finished, rules are added to agenda queue for execution.
RHS execution order is indeterministic unless you use `salience`. Rules with bigger salience will be executed first.
If a rule changes state of the object while execution, next queued rule will be removed from agenda queue if LHS no longer matches.

If I understood you right, you need `salience 1` for rule-2

Comment: Thanks but it's not working for me...I think my problem is similar with this one:[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37850100/issue-with-modify-keyword-in-drools) link. But its solution still not working for me...

Comment: I  had hard time reading your question, now I have two. The 'upvote' is to give some credits to the new contributor, not because this is great question. Now please, write a junit test with assert statement inside which fail. So that to be clear of your expectation and be able to check the fix